# Make a symbolic link to a relative pathname

Tags: symlink

I can do this:

```
$ pwd
/home/beau
$ ln -s /home/beau/foo/bar.txt /home/beau/bar.txt
$ readlink -f bar.txt
/home/beau/foo/bar.txt
```

But I'd like to be able to do this:

```
$ pwd
/home/beau
$ cd foo
$ ln -s bar.txt /home/beau/bar.txt
$ readlink -f /home/beau/bar.txt
/home/beau/foo/bar.txt
```

Is this possible? Can I somehow resolve the relative pathname and pass it to `ln`?

Comment: But what is the problem that it would be solved with the described behavior?

Comment: Well, say you offer a compressed folder for download, and would like to give copy-pastable instructions on how to symlink some of the folder's files.

Comment: `ln -s $(pwd)/bar.txt ~/` or include an install script.

Comment: the link stores actually the name you use on command line. The resolution of that name to a file is done relative to the link location. You have to use `ln -s foo/bar.txt /home/beau/bar.txt`

Answer (score 118):

If you create a symbolic link to a relative path, it will store it as a relative symbolic link, not absolute like your example shows.  This is generally a good thing. Absolute symbolic links don't work when the filesystem is mounted elsewhere.

The reason your example doesn't work is that it's relative to the parent directory of the symbolic link and not where `ln` is run.

You can do:

```
$ pwd
/home/beau
$ ln -s foo/bar.txt bar.txt
$ readlink -f /home/beau/bar.txt
/home/beau/foo/bar.txt
```

Or for that matters:

```
$ cd foo
$ ln -s foo/bar.txt ../bar.txt
```

It's important to realise that the first argument after `ln -s` is stored as the target of the symlink. It can be any arbitrary string (with the only restrictions that it can't be empty and can't contain the NUL character), but at the time the symlink is being used and resolved, that string is understood as a relative path to the parent directory of the symlink (when it doesn't start with `/`).

Comment: Nicely said. You answered this while I was typing my own answer. :)

Comment: I just had a slightly different question - and this answers it perfectly. I wanted to know how to reference the home directory in symlink so it would work when I transferred it from one user to another. I wasn't sure if something like `~` would work.

Comment: "that string is understood as a relative path to the parent directory of the symlink" - this explains everything!

Comment: @Joe I think to be perfect on that point it'd have to mention that `~` is expanded by the shell itself, while `.` isn't. It's a mistake I make constantly at least, when using `ln`.

Answer (score 58):

If you use newer coreutils (I'm using coreutils-8.22-11), it has an option to do that:

```
ln --help | grep relative
can hold arbitrary text; if later resolved, a relative link is
  -r, --relative              create symbolic links relative to link location
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ touch /tmp/test/to
$ ln -rs /tmp/test/to /tmp/test/from
$ ls -l /tmp/test/from
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 ptr ptr 4 aug   25 17.02 /tmp/test/to -> from
```

Comment: Hm, for me it seems there is no such option `-r`. Using Mac though.

Comment: @ivkremer it seems this option is available since `coreutils` >= 8.16 (source: https://superuser.com/a/837935/403979)

Comment: Using the relative flag seemed to clear up the issues of "too many levels of symbolic links" I was experiencing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry, no. Symbolic links are relative to the location the link is in, not the location you were when you created the link. There are several good reasons for this behavior, most of which involve mounting remote filesystems.

Answer (score 9):

There's a convenient little utility called [`symlinks`](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks) (originally by Mark Lord, now maintained by J. Brandt Buckley), present in many Linux distributions.

To convert all the absolute symbolic links in a directory to be relative:

```
symlinks -c /path/to/directory
```

Unfortunately there's no option to convert a single link, you'd have to move it to its own directory first.

```
mkdir ../tmp
mv link-to-relativize ../tmp
symlinks ../tmp
mv ../tmp/* .
rmdir ../tmp
```

Comment: thanks. symlinks available on [github](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks). Maintained by J. Brandt Buckley. [v1.4.3](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks/releases/tag/v1.4.3).

Comment: This tool is of limited utility. It only repairs absolute symlinks that are valid, relative to the absolute root. For instance, say I have a file system tree `tree/` which contains `tree/bin/foo -> /bin/bar`. There is no way to tell `symlinks` that `tree` is the "sysroot", such that `/bin/bar` is supposed to refer to `tree/bin/bar` (from where I'm sitting) and therefore the correct way to relativize it is to rewrite it to just `bar`.  To the `symlinks` utility, this looks like a dangling link; all it can do is delete it.

Answer (score 5):

As the most common shells expands paths, to create a relative symlink you should quote the "source path".

Also, the `-s` parameter means `--symbolic`. `ln` creates hard links by default.

```
$ ln -s '../../relative_path' path
$ ls -al path

lrwxrwxrwx 1 empjustine empjustine 19 Aug  6 01:38 path -> ../../relative/path
```

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
ln -s `pwd`/bar.txt /home/beau/bar.txt
```

But, it makes a symbolic link to the absolute pathname. Your textual question asks mentions relative pathname...

Normally, a relative pathname is what you want, and what `ln -s` gives you.
I think what you want is:

```
cd /home/beau
ln -s foo/bar.txt bar.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain there is no chance of your mount points changing you can achieve what you are trying to do in a bash shell like this:

```
ln -s `pwd`/bar.txt ~/bar.txt
```

This assumes that you are in the target directory when making the symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to create a relative path I follow the pattern given below

```bash
# CD into the directory where you want the symlink to be (ie the target)
$ cd projX/subdir1
$ pwd
/Users/USERX/repoX/projX/subdir1

# relative path to the source of the file you want for the symlink, put it in the cwd
$ ln -s ../subdir2/file_foo.txt .

# Verify the symlink is as expected
$ readlink /Users/USERX/repoX/projX/subdir2/file_foo.txt
../subdir1/file_foo.txt
```